# jquery selector in bootstrap modal with dropdown-menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal with several dropdown menues. What I want is that when i click an item in One of the dropdown list - the modal should close - the clicked text should be grabbed and placed in a anchor tag called "choice" in the span "target".

this is the script i tried, but it did not Work:

```
<script>
    $(" .dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        $("#target").text($(this).text());
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

    });
</script>
```

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h2 class="modal-title">Tittle"</h2>
                </div>
            <!-- Modal Body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id=" menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing1</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing2</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing3</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing5</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing6</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing7</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing8</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">Fafairs</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">somthing</a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#choice">Other</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal Footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer">
    <a name="choice"></a>
</div>
<h2><span class="label label-danger">Here goes  <span id="target"></span>  text</span></h2>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://www.bootply.com/fx5K2BaVIV#

Comment: Thank you Sebsemillia for a great wakeup call. I put my script in the view instead of the layoutpage. Thank you